# Calculate the probability of intersection

Tags: probability

In a certain Algebra 2 class of 30 students, 22 of them play basketball and 18 of them play baseball. There are 3 students who play neither sport. What is the probability that a student chosen randomly from the class plays both basketball and baseball?

I know how to calculate the probability of students play both basketball and baseball which is $\frac {13}{30}$ because $22+18+3=43$ and $43-30$ will give you the number of students plays both sports.

But how would you find the probability using the formula $P(A \cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$?

Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 3):

That formula only works if events $A$ (play basketball) and $B$ (play baseball) are independent, but they are not in this case, since out of the $18$ players that play baseball, $13$ play basketball, and hence $P(A|B) = \frac{13}{18} < \frac{22}{30} = P(A)$ (in other words: one who plays basketball is less likely to play basketball as well in comparison to someone who does not play baseball, i.e. playing baseball and playing basketball are negatively (or inversely) correlated)

So: the two events are *not* independent, and so that formula doesn't work.

Fortunately, a formula that *does* work (always!) is:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Hence:

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = \frac{22}{30} + \frac{18}{30} - \frac{27}{30} = \frac{13}{30}$$

Comment: Ok. So the word "and" does not always indicate you should multiply the probabilities? I didn't know such formula exists.

Comment: @Lily That's right, that only works for independent events, i.e. where the presence or absence of event $B$ has no effect on the probability of event $A$.

Comment: The formula you introduced would work for any dependent events such as finding the probability of drawing an ace the 1st time, and then another ace the second time without replacement from a deck of cards?

Comment: But then that won't make any sense... because even this this two events are dependent, you still have to multiply (4/52)(3/51), which is not the same result as (4/52)+(3/51)-(4/51)

Comment: @Lily Note that the probability of drawing an ace for the second card is not 3/51 ... that is the probability of drawing an ace as the second card *given* drawing an ace for the 1st card. So: P(A2|A1) = 3/51, but P(A2) is simply 4/52

Comment: I guess my question is when do you know you should use the formula that you introduced...

Comment: @Lily You can always use the formula I indicated, whether the events are dependent or independent.

Answer (score 0):

The events playing of basketball and baseball are not independent. Hence, you cannot use the formula that you suggested.

You need to use: $\Pr(Basketball \cap Baseball) = \Pr(Basketball) + \Pr(Baseball) - \Pr(Basketball \cup Baseball).$